# Insert com duas tabelas

Tags: php, pdo

Segue meu código, primeira query com as informações da **tabela alunos**.
Segunda query com as informações da **tabela pagamentos**.

No meu cadastro, tenho as informações de alunos e pagamentos juntos. Quero que ao cadastrar seja feito o cadastro das duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo.

```
<?php

    class Alunos 
    {
     /* 
     * class cadastrar()
     * Realiza o cadastro dos alunos
     */

     public function 
     cadastrar($nome,$rg,$cpf,$nascimento,$sexo,$fone,$email,
     $endereco,$bairro,$cidade,$estado,$cep)
            {

                global $pdo;

                $sql = $pdo->prepare("insert into alunos set nome=:nome, rg=:rg, 
                cpf=:cpf, nascimento=:nascimento, sexo=:sexo,
                fone=:fone, email=:email, endereco=:endereco,
                bairro=:bairro, cidade=:cidade, estado=:estado, cep=:cep");

                $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
                $sql->bindValue(":rg", $rg);
                $sql->bindValue(":cpf", $cpf);
                $sql->bindValue(":nascimento", $nascimento);
                $sql->bindValue(":sexo", $sexo);
                $sql->bindValue(":fone", $fone);
                $sql->bindValue(":email", $email);
                $sql->bindValue(":endereco", $endereco);
                $sql->bindValue(":bairro", $bairro);
                $sql->bindValue(":cidade", $cidade);
                $sql->bindValue(":estado", $estado);
                $sql->bindValue(":cep", $cep);
                $sql->execute();

            }

     /*
     * class pagamentos()
     * Realiza o cadastro dos alunos
     */

       public function pagamentos($situacao_aluno,$vencimento_plano,
       $planos,$vencimento,$cpf_amigo,$forma_pagamento,$data_matricula,
       $numero_documento,$data_documento,$valor)
       {

      global $pdo; 
      $sql = $pdo->prepare("insert into pagamentos set 
      situacao_aluno=:situacao_aluno, vencimento_plano=:vencimento_plano, 
      planos=:planos, vencimento=:vencimento, cpf_amigo=:cpf_amigo, 
      forma_pagamento=:forma_pagamento, data_matricula=:data_matricula, 
      numero_documento=:numero_documento, data_documento=:data_documento, 
      valor=:valor");

        $sql->bindValue(":situacao_aluno", $situacao_aluno);
        $sql->bindValue(":vencimento_plano", $vencimento_plano);
        $sql->bindValue(":planos", $planos);
        $sql->bindValue(":vencimento", $vencimento);
        $sql->bindValue(":cpf_amigo", $cpf_amigo);
        $sql->bindValue(":forma_pagamento", $forma_pagamento);
        $sql->bindValue(":data_matricula", $data_matricula);
        $sql->bindValue(":numero_documento", $numero_documento);
        $sql->bindValue(":data_documento", $data_documento);
        $sql->bindValue(":valor", $valor);
        $sql->execute();

           }
```

Sei que existem as funções `last_insert_id();`, `mysql_insert_id();` e `mysqli_insert_id();` mas não sei como aplicar no meu código que está com pdo orientado a obj.

Comment: Faz tempo que não uso PHP, mas acho que voce recupera o id com algo parecido $sql->lastInsertId() depois do execute, e usa como parametro pra proxima.. não sei se entendi direito tua duvida.

Answer (score 1):

Não ficou claro se a tabela **pagamentos** possui uma foreign key do aluno, pelo insert não parece ter, mas pode ser que seja a **situacao_aluno**?

Primeiro tu muda a função **cadastrar** para retorna o id dessa forma utilizando [isso](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php):

```
public function cadastrar(/* parâmetros */)
{
    // faz a tua lógica de inserção

    return $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

Segunda alteração é no lugar onde essa função é chamada, tu deve fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$aluno = new Aluno();
$idAluno = $aluno->cadastrar(/** parâmetros */);
$aluno->pagamentos($idAluno /** resto dos parâmetros */);
```

E por último deve também ser alterada a **pagamentos** para utilizar o id do aluno, que como disse pode ser que tenha uma coluna **aluno_id** para fazer o vínculo ou é essa tal de **situacao_aluno**.

Comment: Também fiquei em dúvida quanto a fk do aluno, mas também creio que seja a situação _aluno. Se for, usar a lógica de retornar o id da inserção e usar o mesmo pra registrar o pagamento é uma boa solução pro problema/dúvida. O que eu talvez mudaria seria tirar a função de registrar pagamento da classe do aluno e criar uma classe própria pra pagamentos e usar essa função nela.

Comment: Sim, minha foreign key é o id_alunos que está na tabela pagamentos...
@Melissa fiz o que recomendou, porém não vai.

Comment: oi @VerônicaEmschermann pode elaborar melhor? oque não ta funcionando, da algum erro? ele inseri o aluno e não o pagamento? quem sabe poste o código após as modificações que sugeri.

Answer (score 0):

**GALERA CONSEGUI RESOLVER DA SEGUINTE FORMA :**

```
 <?php
 class Alunos 
 {
 /* 
 * class cadastrar()
 * Realiza o cadastro dos alunos
 */

public function cadastrar($nome,$rg,$cpf,$nascimento,$sexo,$fone,$email,$endereco,
$bairro,$cidade,$estado,$cep)
{

global $pdo;

$sql = $pdo->prepare("insert into alunos set nome=:nome, rg=:rg, cpf=:cpf, 
nascimento=:nascimento, sexo=:sexo,fone=:fone, email=:email, 
endereco=:endereco,bairro=:bairro, cidade=:cidade, estado=:estado, cep=:cep");

            $sql->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
            $sql->bindValue(":rg", $rg);
            $sql->bindValue(":cpf", $cpf);
            $sql->bindValue(":nascimento", $nascimento);
            $sql->bindValue(":sexo", $sexo);
            $sql->bindValue(":fone", $fone);
            $sql->bindValue(":email", $email);
            $sql->bindValue(":endereco", $endereco);
            $sql->bindValue(":bairro", $bairro);
            $sql->bindValue(":cidade", $cidade);
            $sql->bindValue(":estado", $estado);
            $sql->bindValue(":cep", $cep);
            $sql->execute();

}


/*
* class pagamentos()
* Realiza o cadastro dos alunos
*/

 public function pagamentos($email,$situacao_aluno,$vencimento_plano,
 $planos,$vencimento,$cpf_amigo,$forma_pagamento,$data_matricula,
 $numero_documento,$data_documento,$valor)
 {
  global $pdo; 

  $sql = $pdo->prepare("insert into pagamentos set email_pagamento =:email_pagamento, 
  situacao_aluno=:situacao_aluno, vencimento_plano=:vencimento_plano, planos=:planos, 
  vencimento=:vencimento,cpf_amigo=:cpf_amigo, forma_pagamento=:forma_pagamento, 
  data_matricula=:data_matricula, numero_documento=:numero_documento, 
  data_documento=:data_documento, valor=:valor");

    $sql->bindValue(":email_pagamento", $email);
    $sql->bindValue(":situacao_aluno", $situacao_aluno);
    $sql->bindValue(":vencimento_plano", $vencimento_plano);
    $sql->bindValue(":planos", $planos);
    $sql->bindValue(":vencimento", $vencimento);
    $sql->bindValue(":cpf_amigo", $cpf_amigo);
    $sql->bindValue(":forma_pagamento", $forma_pagamento);
    $sql->bindValue(":data_matricula", $data_matricula);
    $sql->bindValue(":numero_documento", $numero_documento);
    $sql->bindValue(":data_documento", $data_documento);
    $sql->bindValue(":valor", $valor);
    $sql->execute();

    $this->idAluno($email);

 }


  private function idAluno($email) {

    global $pdo;

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("select * from alunos where email = :email");
    $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $sql->execute();

    if($sql->rowCount() > 0) { 
    foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $rowAluno){   


    $sql = $pdo->prepare("update pagamentos set alunos_id = :alunos_id
    where email_pagamento = :email_pagamento");

    $sql->bindValue(':alunos_id', $rowAluno['id_alunos']);
    $sql->bindValue(':email_pagamento', $rowAluno['email']);
    $sql->execute();

        }
      }      
    }
  }
```